# The data source is not embedded within a (parent) data source in AX 2012

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I am facing a strange issue when trying to do picking list of a sales order, following is the error I get. But all other sales orders are working fine, What could be the possible reason for this?

[image: Error when picking a sales order]

Comment: Did you add any code or is standard form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is due to a customization where you are trying to do `.addLink()` on the form. Maybe try `.addDynaLink()` with your customization or investigate the join you are trying to do.